# How can I get tags from event's description

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I'm working on a java project using restFb. In Graph Api references I've found the node "name_tags" for Photo objects ([here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/)) which returns a list of ids.

I'm trying to get the same list for Event objects, but there's no node like that. I can just get the entire description as String from the node "description" which maybe it could contain tags. How could i parse tags? Any workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not working with events that much, so perhaps you can clarify this: How can I add a tag to an event on the Facebook Website? I think this may lead in the right direction. Otherwise you could provide an example of a description that contains tags.

Comment: I've just realized the Description node contains tags in this string format "@[id:another_number:name_tag]". Now I should just need a good Pattern and Regex to extract the ids only from the entire string.